# Source specific multicasting in Pepper API or nacl_io

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

Does `Pepper API` (the base API for `nacl_io`) support source-specific multicasting? Does `setsockopt` work with `IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP` and `IP_DROP_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP` in `nacl_io` ?

Thanks

Comment: The best place to post this kind of feature request issue I think is [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)

Answer (score 2):

The Pepper UDP Socket API (PPB_UDPSocket 1.1) doesn't support source-specific multicast. It is intended to be equivalent to the Chrome Apps UDPSocket API for Javascript.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp

The UDP multicast feature was added recently, and hasn't been exposed through nacl_io yet. It is considered a Dev (not-Stable) API, which means it can only be used in developer scenarios, until the Chrome team determines that it should be made a Stable API.